# How can I get MIME type from base64 String?

Tags: javascript, base64, mime-types

My base64 String looks like `"UklGRkAdEQBXQVZFZm10IBIAAAABAAEAg..."`.
I try to download this file by browser. So,

1. I convert it to blob by function:

```
      b64toBlob: function(b64Data, sliceSize = 512) {
            let byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
            let byteArrays = [];
            for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
                let slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
                let byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
                for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
                    byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
                }
                let byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
                byteArrays.push(byteArray);
            }
            let blob = new Blob(byteArrays);
            return blob;
        }
```

2. Create URL from blob by `URL.createObjectURL(this.b64toBlob(base64))`
3. Emulate click on `<a>` tag with created URL.

Mozilla Firefox recognizes the type of file and offers to download file with correct extension and it's good, but Chrome offers to download txt file regardless the real file type and it's a problem.

I can set the file type, when create a blob file, and Chrome will work correct, but I don`t know, how define correct MIME type from base64.

Comment: You can't detect the mimeType of a stringified file. When files are being stored as a base64, the mimeType is usually saved in the database, and then, after requesting a file from the webserver, the backend will set the appropiate Content-Type and output the decoded base64 string. Using the `attachment` header will prompt the user to download the file.

Comment: If you have the original FILENAME.EXT(extension), you can set the Content-Type to `application/octet-stream`, the browser will save the file *as is*, but the `.EXT` part will allow local apps to open it if there are any viable readers for your file on the user machine.

Answer (score 2):

Read the first character of your base64.

```
content.charAt(0)
```

and keep a switch case with below values to get the type

'/' : jpg

'i' : png

'R' : gif

'U' : webp

Comment: Thanks, but it's not enough. My file may have any type. Not just an image.